# Past Perfect with ago

Tags: past-perfect

How can we use ago with Past perfect? Are below lines correct?

The boy’s father had separated from the family many years ago while his mother worked as a gardener in Mukesh’s school.

Above lines taken from below link of Times of India article. 8/may/2018.

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/dehradun/asked-to-walk-to-school-by-mom-14-year-old-hangs-self/articleshow/64067563.cms?utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=TOI&utm_content=om-bm

Comment: But the rule is we cannot use past perfect with ago..

Comment: Whose rule is that? The sentence looks perfectly grammatical to me.

Comment: *Ago* and *back* (informal) are used for past times from the present moment. *Before* and *earlier* are used for past times from another time in the past.

Comment: But If we refer to a point in time before a specific time in the past, we use before or earlier or previously, often with the past perfect: we dont use ago with past perfect... this is the rule... @TomZych

Comment: @Tom Zych, "me" doesn't mean "everybody".

Comment: I think one has to concede that 'ago', though normally meaning 'before this minute in time' (itself deictic), is also used to mean 'before the time specified as present in the immediate narrative'. 'She had long ago stopped wearing her mini-skirt.'  So here, the extract is insufficient to base a judgement on. / I'd avoid this usage personally, as it can clearly quickly lead to ambiguities.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , So , The boy’s father had separated from the family many years ago in my quesion is incorrect?? We should avoid using "ago" in this kind of phrase?

Comment: Still no further context, but I'd almost certainly prefer 'The boy’s father had separated from the family many years before, at a/the time when his mother was working as a gardener in Mukesh’s school.' There are degrees of 'incorrectness' and different self-appointed judges; I'd not consider this a grievous error.